# HTTP Server fetching Sites folder macOS Big Sur 11.6

Tags: php, apache, http, macos-big-sur

Like the title says, my MacBook Air M1 will nog fetch my Sites folder. I don't think it has any problems finding it, it just only show the old folder.
I followed this guide:
https://tech-cookbook.com/2020/11/14/setting-up-your-local-web-server-on-macos-big-sur-11-0-1-2020-mamp-macos-apache-mysql-php/

Do you guys have any idea why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got the answer. I saw a lot of other people have the problem. As long as you follow all the steps above you need to do the following:

`§ sudo apachectl stop`

Restart Mac

`§ sudo apachectl start`

Yes... I am not kidding